# Calculate Sen Slopes on time series data set with different sites

Tags: r, list

I would like to calculate the sens slope of a time serie organized by stations.

```
    date    station value
01/05/2007  1001    12.27
01/06/2007  1001    12.33
01/07/2007  1001    6.26
01/08/2007  1001    2.75
01/09/2007  1001    1.15
01/10/2007  1001    3.68
01/11/2007  1001    4.72
01/12/2007  1001    6.16
01/01/2008  1001    7.80
01/02/2008  1001    8.42
01/03/2008  1001    8.85
01/04/2008  1001    9.55
01/05/2008  1001    11.44
01/06/2008  1001    12.90
01/07/2008  1001    11.67
01/08/2008  1001    2.56
01/09/2008  1001    2.72
01/10/2008  1001    3.30
01/11/2008  1001    4.82
01/12/2008  1001    5.77
01/01/2009  1001    6.65
01/02/2009  1001    7.35
01/03/2009  1001    8.53
01/04/2009  1001    10.75
01/05/2009  1001    12.02
01/06/2009  1001    13.68
01/07/2009  1001    9.36
01/08/2009  1001    9.18
01/09/2009  1001    6.10
01/10/2009  1001    8.36
01/11/2009  1001    8.86
01/12/2009  1001    9.67
01/01/2010  1001    10.49
01/02/2010  1001    11.36
01/03/2010  1001    12.05
01/04/2010  1001    13.74
01/05/2010  1001    14.75
01/06/2010  1001    15.28
01/07/2010  1001    13.87
01/08/2010  1001    2.66
01/09/2010  1001    1.84
01/10/2010  1001    2.49
01/11/2010  1001    3.55
01/12/2010  1001    6.27
01/01/2011  1001    6.73
01/02/2011  1001    8.64
01/03/2011  1001    9.85
01/04/2011  1001    10.91
01/05/2011  1001    12.31
01/06/2011  1001    12.93
01/07/2011  1001    8.89
01/08/2011  1001    3.84
01/05/2016  1511    21.22
01/06/2016  1511    21.88
01/07/2016  1511    21.15
01/08/2016  1511    20.25
01/09/2016  1511    14.70
01/10/2016  1511    7.63
01/11/2016  1511    8.00
01/12/2016  1511    8.16
01/01/2017  1511    8.41
01/02/2017  1511    10.27
01/03/2017  1511    11.28
01/04/2017  1511    13.82
01/05/2017  1511    14.77
01/06/2017  1511    16.35
01/07/2017  1511    17.26
01/08/2017  1511    13.47
01/09/2017  1511    11.06
01/10/2017  1511    5.98
01/11/2017  1511    6.81
01/12/2017  1511    7.82
01/02/2018  1511    9.02
01/03/2018  1511    9.82
01/04/2018  1511    10.24
01/05/2018  1511    9.23
01/06/2018  1511    9.32
01/07/2018  1511    9.06
01/08/2018  1511    7.55
01/09/2018  1511    9.00
01/10/2018  1511    8.35
01/11/2018  1511    8.46
01/10/2007  1512    7.08
01/11/2007  1512    6.71
01/12/2007  1512    7.41
01/01/2008  1512    7.87
01/02/2008  1512    8.27
01/03/2008  1512    8.63
01/04/2008  1512    3.64
01/05/2008  1512    8.91
01/06/2008  1512    8.89
01/07/2008  1512    9.54
01/08/2008  1512    7.82
01/09/2008  1512    6.76
01/10/2008  1512    6.74
01/11/2008  1512    6.66
01/12/2008  1512    6.06
01/01/2009  1512    3.22
01/02/2009  1512    7.12
01/03/2009  1512    7.71
01/04/2009  1512    4.25
01/05/2009  1512    4.85
01/06/2009  1512    8.96
01/07/2009  1512    5.48
01/08/2009  1512    9.87
01/09/2009  1512    9.64
01/10/2009  1512    8.88
01/11/2009  1512    9.12
01/12/2009  1512    9.49
01/01/2010  1512    10.08
01/02/2010  1512    10.26
01/03/2010  1512    10.59
01/04/2010  1512    11.88
01/07/2017  1515    5.92
01/08/2017  1515    5.64
01/09/2017  1515    4.93
01/10/2017  1515    4.05
01/11/2017  1515    4.17
01/12/2017  1515    4.64
01/02/2018  1515    4.80
01/03/2018  1515    5.36
01/04/2018  1515    5.72
01/05/2018  1515    5.72
01/06/2018  1515    6.01
01/07/2018  1515    6.26
01/08/2018  1515    5.33
01/09/2018  1515    5.13
01/10/2018  1515    4.22
01/11/2018  1515    4.19
01/12/2018  1515    4.59
01/01/2019  1515    4.70
01/07/2019  1515    7.23
```

Hi,
I have this dataframe and I m able to calculate Mann Kendall test with this code:

```
#function to perform Mann Kendall test
MK <- function(x){
  
  MKfun <- possibly(Kendall::MannKendall, 
                    list(tau  = NA_real_,
                         sl   = NA_real_,
                         S    = NA_real_,
                         D    = NA_real_,
                         varS = NA_real_))
  out <- MKfun(x)
  class(out) <- "list"
  data.frame(out)}

#calling functions and store it in a dataframe
TS_MK <-
  TS %>%
  group_by(station) %>% 
  summarise(N     = n(),
            MK(value))
```

But I wanted to calculate the sen's slope and when I try this:

```
sens.slope(value)
```

I have this error:

```
Erreur : Problem with `summarise()` column `SEN`.
i `SEN = sens.slope(WL_m)`.
x `SEN` must be a vector, not a `htest` object.
i The error occurred in group 1: station = 1001.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `summarise()` column `SEN`.
i `SEN = sens.slope(WL_m)`.
x `SEN` must be a vector, not a `htest` object.
i The error occurred in group 1: station = 1001.
```

How to calculate the sen slope? And in the same time than the Mann Kandall test if it's possible to have everything in the same data frame at the end.
Thanks for your help.

------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

Here is my last code version (thanks @AKRUN) and still it doesnt work:

```
    library(trend)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(Kendall)

#Loading data
TS = read.csv('Data/DATA.csv',sep=';')


#Calculate Mann Kendall test values for each station
TS %>% 
  mutate(value = readr::parse_number(value)) %>% 
  group_by(station) %>% 
  summarise(N = n(), out = list(MK(value))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(c(out))

#calculate Sen slope value for each station
TS %>% 
  mutate(value = readr::parse_number(value)) %>% 
  group_by(station) %>% 
  summarise(out = list(broom::tidy(sens.slope(value))))  %>% 
  unnest(out)
```

I have these errors:

```
Erreur : Problem with `mutate()` column `value`.
i `value = readr::parse_number(value)`.
x is.character(x) is not TRUE
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I tried to change the value in character but still it doesnt work....

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'value' column is not `numeric` class as there is `,` in the values.  We can either remove the `,` and convert to numeric with `as.numeric` or use `parse_number` from `readr` to extract numeric part.  Also, in the `summarise`, it may be better to wrap in a `list` (as the function returns a `data.frame`) which can be later `unnest`ed

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
TS %>% 
   mutate(value = readr::parse_number(value)) %>% 
   group_by(station) %>% 
   summarise(N = n(), out = list(MK(value))) %>% 
   unnest_wider(c(out))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  station     N     tau      sl     S     D   varS
    <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1    1001    52  0.176  0.0660    234 1326. 16059.
2    1511    30 -0.361  0.00538  -157  435.  3142.
3    1512    31  0.351  0.00590   163  465.  3462.
4    1515    19  0.0352 0.861       6  170.   816
```

---

With `sens.slope`, the output is in a `list` structure.  We can `tidy` up the output to return a `tibble`

```
library(broom)
library(trend)
TS %>% 
   mutate(value = readr::parse_number(value)) %>% 
   group_by(station) %>% 
   summarise(out = list(broom::tidy(sens.slope(value))))  %>% 
   unnest(out)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  station statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method      alternative
    <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      
1    1001     1.84  0.0660         52   -0.351      15.4 Sen's slope two.sided  
2    1511    -2.78  0.00538        30  -48.6        -8.5 Sen's slope two.sided  
3    1512     2.75  0.00590        31    4.2        20.5 Sen's slope two.sided  
4    1515     0.175 0.861          19   -7.18       13.5 Sen's slope two.sided
```

#### data

```
TS <- structure(list(date = c("01/05/2007", "01/06/2007", "01/07/2007", 
"01/08/2007", "01/09/2007", "01/10/2007", "01/11/2007", "01/12/2007", 
"01/01/2008", "01/02/2008", "01/03/2008", "01/04/2008", "01/05/2008", 
"01/06/2008", "01/07/2008", "01/08/2008", "01/09/2008", "01/10/2008", 
"01/11/2008", "01/12/2008", "01/01/2009", "01/02/2009", "01/03/2009", 
"01/04/2009", "01/05/2009", "01/06/2009", "01/07/2009", "01/08/2009", 
"01/09/2009", "01/10/2009", "01/11/2009", "01/12/2009", "01/01/2010", 
"01/02/2010", "01/03/2010", "01/04/2010", "01/05/2010", "01/06/2010", 
"01/07/2010", "01/08/2010", "01/09/2010", "01/10/2010", "01/11/2010", 
"01/12/2010", "01/01/2011", "01/02/2011", "01/03/2011", "01/04/2011", 
"01/05/2011", "01/06/2011", "01/07/2011", "01/08/2011", "01/05/2016", 
"01/06/2016", "01/07/2016", "01/08/2016", "01/09/2016", "01/10/2016", 
"01/11/2016", "01/12/2016", "01/01/2017", "01/02/2017", "01/03/2017", 
"01/04/2017", "01/05/2017", "01/06/2017", "01/07/2017", "01/08/2017", 
"01/09/2017", "01/10/2017", "01/11/2017", "01/12/2017", "01/02/2018", 
"01/03/2018", "01/04/2018", "01/05/2018", "01/06/2018", "01/07/2018", 
"01/08/2018", "01/09/2018", "01/10/2018", "01/11/2018", "01/10/2007", 
"01/11/2007", "01/12/2007", "01/01/2008", "01/02/2008", "01/03/2008", 
"01/04/2008", "01/05/2008", "01/06/2008", "01/07/2008", "01/08/2008", 
"01/09/2008", "01/10/2008", "01/11/2008", "01/12/2008", "01/01/2009", 
"01/02/2009", "01/03/2009", "01/04/2009", "01/05/2009", "01/06/2009", 
"01/07/2009", "01/08/2009", "01/09/2009", "01/10/2009", "01/11/2009", 
"01/12/2009", "01/01/2010", "01/02/2010", "01/03/2010", "01/04/2010", 
"01/07/2017", "01/08/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/10/2017", "01/11/2017", 
"01/12/2017", "01/02/2018", "01/03/2018", "01/04/2018", "01/05/2018", 
"01/06/2018", "01/07/2018", "01/08/2018", "01/09/2018", "01/10/2018", 
"01/11/2018", "01/12/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/07/2019"), station = c(1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 
1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 
1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 
1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 1511L, 
1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 
1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 
1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 
1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 
1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 
1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L, 1515L), value = c("12,27", "12,33", 
"6,26", "2,75", "1,15", "3,68", "4,72", "6,16", "7,80", "8,42", 
"8,85", "9,55", "11,44", "12,90", "11,67", "2,56", "2,72", "3,30", 
"4,82", "5,77", "6,65", "7,35", "8,53", "10,75", "12,02", "13,68", 
"9,36", "9,18", "6,10", "8,36", "8,86", "9,67", "10,49", "11,36", 
"12,05", "13,74", "14,75", "15,28", "13,87", "2,66", "1,84", 
"2,49", "3,55", "6,27", "6,73", "8,64", "9,85", "10,91", "12,31", 
"12,93", "8,89", "3,84", "21,22", "21,88", "21,15", "20,25", 
"14,70", "7,63", "8,00", "8,16", "8,41", "10,27", "11,28", "13,82", 
"14,77", "16,35", "17,26", "13,47", "11,06", "5,98", "6,81", 
"7,82", "9,02", "9,82", "10,24", "9,23", "9,32", "9,06", "7,55", 
"9,00", "8,35", "8,46", "7,08", "6,71", "7,41", "7,87", "8,27", 
"8,63", "3,64", "8,91", "8,89", "9,54", "7,82", "6,76", "6,74", 
"6,66", "6,06", "3,22", "7,12", "7,71", "4,25", "4,85", "8,96", 
"5,48", "9,87", "9,64", "8,88", "9,12", "9,49", "10,08", "10,26", 
"10,59", "11,88", "5,92", "5,64", "4,93", "4,05", "4,17", "4,64", 
"4,80", "5,36", "5,72", "5,72", "6,01", "6,26", "5,33", "5,13", 
"4,22", "4,19", "4,59", "4,70", "7,23")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-132L))
```

Comment: Yes indeed my bad!! I made some edit to the initial file! I have a error on sens.slope calculation! THanks!!

Comment: Well actually, I'm still not able to calculate sens slope :)

Comment: @dudpant based on your input, I don't get any error though

Comment: Could you use the function sens.slope(value)?

Comment: @dudpant where is the `sens.slope` coming from i.e .from which package

Comment: @dudpant is it from 'trend'

Comment: @dudpant you can check the updated solution

Comment: I see that you add a letter to the station, is there a reason?

Comment: Erreur : Problem with `mutate()` column `value`.
i `value = readr::parse_number(value)`.
x is.character(x) is not TRUE

Comment: @dudpant if you have a `factor` column, use `value = readr::parse_number(as.character(value))`

Comment: OK now it works perfectly! I had some anomalies in my data file (single value made the sens slope calculation bugged).
THanks a lot!!